# Why is printing to console a bottleneck?

Tags: rust

In [Rust High Performance](https://www.packtpub.com/product/rust-high-performance/9781788399487), on page 27, the author wrote:

> The problem is that if you are trying to print an integer, for example, a bottleneck
> appears. That's what happened some time ago to Robert Grosse, and he wrote an article
> about it.
> Long story short, he had to force the copying of the integer. How did he do that? Well, it's
> as simple as creating a scope that will return that integer. Since integers implement Copy,
> the integer will be copied to the scope and then returned, effectively copying it to the
> macro: `let my_int = 76_u32; println!("{}", {my_int});`

Why does the author claim it is a bottleneck print an integer? Such that it even results in a workaround of creating a new scope for the sole purpose of copying the passed-in integer?

I searched for [Robert Grosse](https://medium.com/@robertgrosse) but couldn't find the mentioned article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the reverenced article is [how copying an int made my code 11 times faster by Robert Grosse](https://medium.com/@robertgrosse/how-copying-an-int-made-my-code-11-times-faster-f76c66312e0f).

The problem was apparently the following (spelled out about a third down the page):

> while Rust knows that the borrow is immutable [nb: `println!` always implicitly borrows its parameters], this information is sadly not passed to LLVM. This means that the LLVM optimizer sees that a pointer to `size` is being passed to some function and just gives up, leaving the following code to assume that `size` holds an arbitrary value.

Robert then shows the assembly, and that clarifies things: it's not that `println!` bottlenecks the code, it's that the `println!` causes an optimization failure (or a deoptimisation): LLVM's assumed that `println!` might keep a handle on `&size`, so on every iteration it had to re-load the size, perform the modulo, and perform a bounds check.

Comment: the more and more println prove being bad.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with `println` itself, it has to do with the expressivity of the IR, and the visibility of the thing to the optimiser. You can replace `println!` by an `extern` function and you will see similar issues.

Comment: it's not the first time I hear about problem with macro println, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75939406/in-rust-why-does-integer-overflow-sometimes-cause-compilation-error-or-runtime